Tomcat v8.5 not shown inside eclipse
Hello I'm trying to create an apache tomcat v8.5 inside eclipse but when I choose create new server the latest tomcat version is 8.0.
I tried to install all the possible plugins for it to work but still didn't show up
The version of eclipse that I use is Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0)
Build id: 20231201-2043

As a web developer, you should use the Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers rather than the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers IDE package. And you should also use the current version of Eclipse which is currently 2024-03.

You must have an older version of the relevant plug-in installed. Which one did you install, and how?

The Marketplace entry for the "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers", includes support for Tomcat v8.5, if you make sure that optional feature is checked as you walk through the marketplace install wizard.
If you're using the "Eclipse JST Server Adapters (Apache Tomcat, JOnAS, J2EE)" marketplace entry, please remove it. It's been outdated for years at this point, and only points to the 2015 revision of the same feature as above, regardless of which release of Eclipse you're using.
